# Neo4j - Connecting to a database using SSL client authentication by Java driver v4.4.11 and above

Tags: neo4j

I still could not find any methods relating to SSL **Client** authentication in neo4j-java-driver-4.4.11.jar (java 8).

I knew that was not supported in old version long time ago: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/513

But 4 years passed so I would like to confirm if **SSL Client** authentication is supported now in Neo4j **java driver** version 4.4.11 and above or not?

Any information would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I tried looking inside the code of Neo4j Java driver 4.4.11 but could not find functions related to SSL client authentication, I only found Server authentication method.
I also didn't see any documentation telling that driver 4.4.11 suppports SSL client authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Client SSL auth is not supported in any of the drivers, only server-to-server between members of a Neo4j cluster.

It is requested periodically, and is under consideration.

Out of interest, are you looking for 1st factor authentication (a trusted client certificate is sufficient to log into the DBMS) or 2nd factor (username / password, plus trusted client cert are required)?

Comment: Hi Richard, I replied here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver/issues/1366#issuecomment-1416698433 . Please have a look. Thank you!